# VueJS : "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' with webpack < 5 used to include polyfills"

Tags: vue.js, http, webpack, axios, polyfills

I am developing a VueJS application. The version is @vue/cli 5.0.8, and my NodeJS version is v18.15.0.

I am using **an old code** from a friend that **uses axios** to call an API. The configuration of the axios has the **httpAgent configuration**. It declares a new httpAgent with the syntax new http.Agent({params}). **But it gave the error** :
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in myaxiosfile.js BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.`

I only know that I should add a code in my webpack configuration file (vue.config.js).
So I did the task :

1. I made the webpack config file (vue inspect > vue.config.js)
2. I added this code to the resolve object :

```
fallback: {
    "http": require.resolve("stream-http")
  }
}
```

The result : from the webpack config file keeps giving ReferenceErrors :

1. `ReferenceError: TerserPlugin is not defined`
2. `ReferenceError: VueLoaderPlugin is not defined`

Does anyone else know a simple solution to use the http library?

Comment: The question lacks the context, what exactly is done, and why. "I am using an old code from a friend that uses axios to call an API" - ask the friend then. You seem to try to use Node code in browser app.

Comment: I have explained what I did (used axios to call an API in a Vue framework). 
What I am dealing with is an error in the axios configuration (httpAgent). 
Even if I could ask the friend, he would not be able to know why I can't use the http in Vue.
 @EstusFlask

Comment: There's just shouldn't be `new http.Agent({params})` in browser code. It's Node code, it cannot be correctly evaluated in a browser. You're trying to solve a problem that shouldn't occur. The way can or cannot be used in browser app is what your friend should have been instructed you in the first place. Not specific to vue or axios.